# Formal languages problem

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

What is meant by L1L2 ?
Does the n have to be the same for both? 
So, aabbcc is an element of L1L2 and aabbcccc is not?
How about the first problem - Epsilon. Is it an element of L1L2? Since n>0 in L1 and L2, Epsilon should not be element of L1L2... But what is meant by L1L2? That's the key to solve all four problems...

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi.
Nop, it does not have to be the same $n$. $L_1L_2=\{xy: x\in L_1,y\in L_2\}$. So, if you want to see if a string is in that set, you want to factor it in two parts, the prefix part must to be in $L_1$ and the suffix part must to be in $L_2$. As an example, $aabbcccc\in L_1L_2$ but $aabb\not \in L_1L_2$.
Hope this helps.

Comment: How about Epsilon? It shouldn't be in L1L2, right?

Comment: nop, it wont. $\epsilon =\epsilon\epsilon$ in order to be in $L_1L_2$, $\epsilon \in L_1$ and $\epsilon \in L_2$ and that is not the case.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!